# cannot load such file -- map_fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 3.2.13 application, there is an import contact page where we can import contacts through csv and if any fields or mapping missing, we can manually map with headers. For this they have used map_fields plugin where most of the code consists in public -> plugins folder.
Now when I try to run the same in 4.2.6 application, this is the error I am facing:

> LoadError - cannot load such file -- map_fields:   activesupport
>   (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in`block
>   in load_dependency'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in`
>   load_dependency'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>
>   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:2:in`
>   '
>   app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in`block
>   in load_file'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in`
>   load_file'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in`
>   load_missing_constant'   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'

This is my controller:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  require 'map_fields'
  map_fields :mapper, ['First Name','Last Name', 'Email', 'Notes'], :file_field => :file, :params => [:contact]

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @contact = @user.contacts.create(contact_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        format.json { render :json => { :notice => 'Contact was successfully created!',:redirect => user_contacts_url} }
        format.html { redirect_to(user_contacts_url(@user), :notice => 'Contact was successfully created!', :type => 'success') }
       else
        format.json { render :json => {:redirect => false} }
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
  def import
    @contact = Contact.new 
  end
    def mapper
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    count = 0

    if fields_mapped?
      mapped_fields.each do |row|
        params[:contact] = {"user_id" => @current_user.id, "firstname" => row[0], "lastname" => row[1], "notes" => row[3], "email" => row[2].try(:strip)}
        contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

        if contact.save
          count = count + 1
        end
      end

      if count > 0
        flash[:notice] = "#{count} Contact(s) created"
        redirect_to :action => :index
      else 
        flash[:notice] = "No contact was created..." 
        redirect_to :action => :index
      end

    else
      @best_row = @rows[1]
      render
    end

    rescue MapFields::InconsistentStateError
      flash[:error] = 'Please try again'
      redirect_to :action => :import
    rescue MapFields::MissingFileContentsError
      flash[:error] = 'Please upload a file'
      redirect_to :action => :import
  end

end
```

Other than this I am having contacts/import.html.erb:

```
<%= semantic_form_for :contact, :url => mapper_user_contacts_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.inputs :name => 'Please select a CSV file to upload' do %>
     <%= f.input :file, :label => false, :as => :file, :input_html => {:name => "file", :id => "file"} %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.buttons do %>
     <%= f.commit_button raw('Import contacts') %>
   <% end %> 
 <% end %>
```

and app/views/contacts/mapper.html.erb:

```
<%= render :partial => 'map_fields/map_fields' %>
```

The above render fields are in vendor -> plugins -> map_fields folder.

Please help me how can I overcome the error? Is data rendered from plugin folder?

Comment: I think your error comes from `require 'map_fields'` in controller. You should have a source for this file. Probably, your Rails does not see that vendor -> plugins -> map_fields folder.

Comment: I did some R & D on this, map_fields can be installed from gem and as well as from plugin. IN my version, they used plugin.

Comment: Plugins in Rails are supposed to be removed in the later versions of Rails anyway, so replace it with a gem.

Comment: Is there any gem to import the contacts and if the header doesn't match we can match automatically?

Comment: You said that map_fields can be installed as gem, so do it.

Comment: This post may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107531/how-to-deal-with-vendor-plugins-after-upgrading-to-rails-3-2-1